# Want to establish relationship in USER and CUSTOMER table

Tags: php, database-design, eloquent, userfrosting

Need some help.

We have installed and working on UserFrosting. In this we have 2 tables one for USER and another for CUSTOMER. So the thing that we want to achieve, want to provide a option from which we can assign a customer in USER.

For this we have created 3rd table where we want to make relationship between USER and CUSTOMER.

The issue is, we want to save Customer id in the 3rd table with User's id. So basically in 3rd table we will show user id and associated customer's id.

So please suggest.

Comment: this is many to many relation ship

Comment: Has a customer has many users or users have many customers? Question is a bit confusing.

Comment: One user can be associated with only one customer.

Comment: @RutvijKothari customer can have multiple users. But User can have only one customer.